# How to use await method inside a flatMap?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlinx.coroutines, rx-kotlin2

my problem is this. I have the next code

```
Observable.fromIterable(this)
            .flatMap { project ->
                val date = async(CommonPool) {
                    App.db.projectResponseDao().getLastUpdate(project.uid.toString())
                }
                val query = ProjectQuery.builder().id(project.uid.toString()).date(date.await()).build()
                val baseGraphQlUrl = context.getString(R.string.base_graphql_url)
                val apolloCall: ApolloCall<ProjectQuery.Data> = ApiClient.getApolloClient(context.getSessionToken(), baseGraphQlUrl).query(query)
                val remoteObservable: Observable<Pair<Project, Response<ProjectQuery.Data>>> = Observable.combineLatest(
                        Observable.just(project),
                        Rx2Apollo.from(apolloCall),
                        BiFunction { localProject, response -> Pair(localProject, response) })
                remoteObservable
            }
```

So, I'm getting a date from a Room table in my android application. I'm using an async method because the room queries need to be done in a different thread from UI. So, with the result, I want to build a new query to a remote database. The problem is I want to be sure that date is already initialized at the moment I create my query. With that in mind, I use await method, but an error is given to me. it said I cant call await function in a no suspend function. So, can you think of a way to solve this? or how to fix it? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is get your Rooms call off the main thread, you can have your `flatMap` code run on an IO thread by adding `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to the end of your code posted above.  Then you don't need to move threads inside `flatMap`.

```
Observable.fromIterable(this)
      .flatMap { project->
      val date = App.db.projectResponseDao().getLastUpdate(project.uid.toString())
      val query = ProjectQuery.builder().id(project.uid.toString()).date(date).build()
      val baseGraphQlUrl = context.getString(R.string.base_graphql_url)
      val apolloCall: ApolloCall<ProjectQuery.Data> = ApiClient.getApolloClient(context.getSessionToken(), baseGraphQlUrl).query(query)
      val remoteObservable: Observable<Pair<Project, Response<ProjectQuery.Data>>> = Observable.combineLatest(
                        Observable.just(project),
                        Rx2Apollo.from(apolloCall),
                        BiFunction { localProject, response -> Pair(localProject, response) })
      remoteObservable
      }
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Comment: Ohhh of course, you are right. I'm gonna test it and put your points in order :D. A little question. Imagine that this flat map is not from an observable. Let's say a normal map from kotlin. How do you archive in that context what I trying to do? How can I use await() to achieve this?

Comment: The code needs to be in suspendable function (annotated with `suspend`), or inside a `launch` or `async` block.